# Why don't I get code coverage results for C++/CLI project in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, code-coverage, testrunconfig

I've recently upgrade my solution to Visual Studio 2010.

I have 4 projects I want to cover using unit tests - 3 C# and 1 C++/CLI.

I get coverage for the C# projects but not for the C++/CLI project.

I did get for all of them in Visual Studio 2008.

I've configured the assemblies using testrunconfig -> Data and Diagnostics -> Code Coverage -> Configure.

Why don't I get code coverage result for the C++/CLI project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out what was wrong.

It appears that the upgrade from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010 removed the profile option (`/PROFILE`).

What was needed to be done was to go to

`Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Advanced -> Profile`

and change this settings to Yes (`/PROFILE`).

Now I get code coverage for the C++/CLI project.